# Generating a random 2D grid with different terrain types clustered together

Tags: random, grid, terrain

I am looking to generate random grid maps consisting of different terrain types (between 2 and 4 types, the ratio of each can be between 0 and 1 with the sum of course adding up to 1).

There should be an additional option to specify whether the different terrain types will be clustered together, scalable between fully random and heavily clustered. I am not sure where to start with that, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Tags: `random`, `grid`, `terrain`. EPIC...

Comment: You should look up `Fractal landscape`